# how to make a connection to a SOAP web service from a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, soap

I want to make a connection to a SOAP web service from a PL/SQL procedure. But I dont know how to do it. I am new to PL/SQL and this is for learning purpose. can anyone explain the process with a simple sample script?
I am using an Oracle SQL developer 12.

I just want a simple script which pass a value as request and return a value as response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to put a request and get the response using [UTL_HTTP package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_http.htm#ARPLS070).

```sql
FUNCTION putRequest_getResponse(mEnvelope VarChar2, mURL VarChar2) 
          RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
    Declare
        mRet                VarChar2(32767) := '';
        mRetCLOB            CLOB := Null;
        mResponseEnvelope   VarChar2(32767);
        mTimeout            NUMBER(4) := 90;
        mReq                UTL_HTTP.req;
        mResp               UTL_HTTP.resp;
    Begin
        UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(mTimeout);
    --
        mReq := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST( mURL, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'Content-Length', length(mEnvelope));
        UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(mReq, 'SOAPAction', mURL);
        UTL_HTTP.WRITE_TEXT(mReq, mEnvelope);
    --  
        mResp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(mReq);
        UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(mResp, mResponseEnvelope);
        UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(mResp);
    --
        mRet := mResponseEnvelope;
    --
      RETURN mRet;
    Exception
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            mRet := 'ERR - putRequest_getResponse' || Chr(10) || SQLERRM;
            Return(mRet);
    End;
END putRequest_getResponse;
```

Depending on the web service you are comunicating with there could be some small differences, but this is the function that I use.
Regards...

Comment: when I am executing a function using UTL_HTTP , I am getting this error " HTTP REQUEST FAILED", "NETWORK ACCESS DENIED BY ACCESS CONTROL LIST". what to do?

Comment: @HarikrishnanAnilkumar you should have priivilage to use it. Ask your dba or if you can - Connect to SYS user with SYSDBA privilege of your database and check the output of the following sql : select acl , principal , privilege , is_grant from DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES